# Boot failure after GRUB failure with no prompt (version 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.2) and Ubuntu reinstall

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have a computer with a Ubuntu+Windows dual boot which has been working fine for years, but turning it on today GRUB is frozen and nothing I can try will change it... I have no prompt, and my keyboard doesn't seem to do anything. See the attached picture I have taken of my screen. [image: GRUB failure screenshot]

I have tried going through my UEFI setup and booting directly to Ubuntu, but what that gives me is the black screen you can see on my picture in full screen, with still no way of interacting with my computer. Doing that, I can boot to Windows just fine (selecting Windows Boot Manager from the list in my UEFI).

The only thing I can think of I did recently that might have done something to GRUB was updating the software on my computer (`sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`), and cleaning up the old OS versions with `sudo apt autoremove` (my computer told me a while ago that my `boot` partition had little space left, that's when I found out that I needed to use `apt autoremove` from time to time to clean that up).

Either way, after that, my laptop battery died while I was writing this post and it wouldn't reboot (I'll ask another question for that soon), so I figure I would try to simply reinstall Ubuntu from a bootable USB to hopefully fix the issue (the option that reinstalls the OS without erasing any of the personal data). I did that, and in the end of the reinstall it just told me something about some apps being broken and that I would need to reinstall them by hand. So I finished the install, but my computer wouldn't turn off and stopped on the second screenshot I'm attaching (sorry for the poor quality of the picture). I know that forcing it to stop wasn't a good idea but I had little choice, and when I tried starting it again this morning it would just stop on the Ubuntu loading page, without even giving me a GRUB menu offering different boot options...[image: Shutdown failure after reinstall screenshot]

So my question really is: how much did I break my computer, and is there anything I can do to fix it without wiping out all my personal data?

Comment: There is a procedure to start from a LiveCD and switch to the installed installation to reinstall Grub. However, if a new install failed that would probably not really help. About accessing your data, you did not say that you tried to access them from the Live CD. Just mount the hard disk and copy your data to an usb drive or to a network share. Or access the HDD from another PC. Then I would consider a full install, because if that fails you might be in for a severe HW issue that would be difficult to remote anlayse anyway. Hope it helps.